# How to find element parent before element with class or id

Tags: jquery

I can't find element previous with attributes `id` that be parent.
in my case element `<p>` is `<tr>`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#c', function(){
   parent = $(this).prev('p#p').text()
   console.log(parent)
})
```

```css
#c {
  padding-left: 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p">parent 1</p>
<p id="c">child 1</p>
<p id="c">child 2</p> 
<p id="c">child 3</p>
<p id="p">parent 2</p>
<p id="c">child 1</p>
<p id="c">child 2</p> 
<p id="c">child 3</p>
```

Comment: id is unique so when you set multiple elements with same id html doest throw error jQuery assumes that you have single element id and returns only one element try class

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`. Use `class` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you can not have same id for multiple elements. The id of each element must be unique. So you can instead use classes. Below is a snippet that serves the purpose.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.c', function() {
  parent = $(this).prevAll('p.p:first').text();
  console.log(parent)
});
```

```css
.c {
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p">parent 1</p>
<p class="c">child 1</p>
<p class="c">child 2</p>
<p class="c">child 3</p>
<p class="p">parent 2</p>
<p class="c">child 1</p>
<p class="c">child 2</p>
<p class="c">child 3</p>
```

Hope this helps :)